# I am getting following error while creating download png using html2Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

While creating a website I was using `html2canvas` which is going to convert text to an image. Conversion is done successfully but while trying to download on button click,
I got the following error :
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAyPu.png)

Can anyone help me out with this please?

PS: I am completely new in web designing

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("myname"), {
  onrendered: function (canvas) {
    var screenshot = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.getElementById("textScreenshot").setAttribute("src", screenshot);
  },
});

btnDownload.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(textScreenshot.msToBlob(), "sg.png");
  } else {
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = screenshot.toDataURL();
    a.download = "sg.png";
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  }
});
```

Error:texttoimg.html:99 Uncaught ReferenceError: screenshot is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show the error text. Please post your error text.

Comment: texttoimg.html:99 Uncaught ReferenceError: screenshot is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>  this is what i got in console

Comment: This is happening because your `screenshot` variable is scoped inside `onrendered` function. You need to take it out and store in a global variable to be able to access it in other function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your `screenshot` variable is locally scoped to your `onrendered` function. You need to take it out and store in a global variable to be able to access it in the other function.

```
let screenshot; // making it global 
window.onload = function(){
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("myname"), {
      onrendered: function (canvas) {
        screenshot = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        document.getElementById("textScreenshot").setAttribute("src", screenshot);
      },
    });
 }

btnDownload.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(textScreenshot.msToBlob(), "sg.png");
  } else {
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = screenshot; // remote toDataURL from here
    a.download = "sg.png";
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  }
});
```

Comment: I am sorry to tell you but I am not able to do it :C

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDataURL' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>

Comment: Please add relevant html code as well and when you are calling that html2canvas function. Try to call it on `window.onload`.

Comment: @Aneel also you need to change `screenshot.toDataURL()` to just `screenshot`, as you are already calling `toDataURL` earlier. Please see my updated answer

Comment: did not require window.onload = function(){ did a great job without it. Thanks a lot, man you saved a lot of my time.  Cheers :D

Comment: No problem. I would still recommend using onload as if your page gets bigger it might not have rendered completely before you call that code.